# Working with jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, events, user-controls

I've been working as a web developer for a couple of years (after previously being a client-server developer), and over the past year I've been focused on making myself better at client-side programming.

My question is more of a fundamental one than something specific.  I've got a couple of ASP user controls that are fieldsets nested within a div.  Both are contained in a div that's a simplemodal jQuery panel.  One is a form for a test submission, and the other is a form that allows you to add a student w/o leaving the modal popup.  Their visibility is toggled when the other becomes visible.

I would do it sequentially (i.e. have them add the student before the test), but the student may already exist, so I've got an autocomplete input set up.  Only if the student doesn't already exist will they add a new one.

I'm handling all of it (including the insert of the student) using client-side code.

I need to have controls with the student's name, id, etc. populate on the test form after being added, but I don't want to explicitly set the controls by ID in the test form b/c I'll be using this panel on other forms.  What would be the best way of implementing this?  My first thought was to handle an event when the student div becomes invisible, but I don't know if such an event exists, and that led me to think there might be a more conventional way altogether.

I hope that all makes sense.  I can post some code if any specifics are needed

Comment: Can you give the controls a generic id, and then set their attributes/values based on your student data? For example, if you have a button with `id="nameButton`, you can set the content like `$("#nameButton").attr("value", student_name);` that way the code still works when you have a different `student_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you are saying... and if you are controlling the visibility of the student div, then you can use the callback method to do the updates. For example:

```
$('#modal .student').hide(function(){
    /* do the update here */
});
```

Otherwise, I think it would depend on the modal plugin and the callbacks it provides.

Comment: That's close to what I meant; the two divs I mentioned are nested in one modal div, so :

`$('.student').hide(function(){
    /* do the update here */
});`

Would I be implementing this callback on every page or user control, then, to update the specific controls that I need?

Comment: It would help if you shared some HTML and maybe elaborated on how the user controls work on the page. Could you bind to the control using a [delegated event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)?

Comment: Thanks for the responses; the info on delegated events is very helpful.

To keep things simple, I'm just going to use the approach Jlange mentioned, as I think I'm overthinking things.  However, the information on events is very helpful, as I'm not familiar with how these work in jQuery / JavaScript at all other than the basic fundamentals of binding and handling.